# How to explain whether Exception will catch RuntimeException?

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception

This is very odd to me. `RuntimeException` inherits from `Exception`, which inherits from `Throwable`.

```
catch(Exception exc) { /* won't catch RuntimeException */
```

but

```
catch(Throwable exc) { /* will catch RuntimeException */
```

I know `RuntimeException` is special in that it's unchecked. But to my understanding that applies just to whether exceptions have to be declared, not whether they are caught. And even then, I don't know why this logic would break on catching `Throwable`.

This is pretty relevant to me since I have a situation where `RuntimeException` can be thrown in a terminal operation. I'm not sure the name for this pattern, but something like, my class `EmailRoller` takes an array of `Callbacks`. The code looks like this:

```
for(Callback cb : callbacks) {
    try {
        cb.call(item);
    }
    catch(Exception exc) {
        logger.error("Error in callback: ", exc);
   }
}
```

So this is a case where something like an OOME needs to fly through, because if one of these callbacks consumes all machine memory, that sure as heck is going to affect the running of the other ones. But a `NullPointerException`? Or an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`? Those will affect the callback but won't prevent the others from running.

Also, this is a bit of an enterprise design. Different programmers or teams can add callbacks to process the item, but they should be isolated from each other. This means, as the programmer responsible for insulating these callbacks from each other, I shouldn't rely on them to make sure errors don't slip through. Catching `Exception` should be about the right line, but it isn't because `RuntimeException` slips through. So my more general question is: what's a good pattern here? Just `catch(Exception | RuntimeException exc)`, which I believe is a syntax error because of the inheritance?

Comment: You should edit the question title - if someone only looks at the title, they will get the idea that catching exception doesn't catch runtime exception.

Comment: @AlexCiminian good point. Here's to another 8 years of informative questions!

Answer (score 176, accepted):

The premise of the question is flawed, because catching `Exception` *does* catch `RuntimeException`. Demo code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            throw new RuntimeException("Bang");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("I caught: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
I caught: java.lang.RuntimeException: Bang
```

Your loop will have problems if:

- `callbacks` is null
- anything modifies `callbacks` while the loop is executing (if it were a collection rather than an array)

Perhaps that's what you're seeing?

Comment: Reread my code. That's correct. My insulation layer was buggy, since the runtime exception came from an `if(results.foo.bar()) { /* apply callback */ }`, which was an NPE.

Comment: @djechlin: Your post doesn't *show* `if (results.foo.bar())` - it's very unclear what you're actually asking at this point...

Comment: Check my post below, Exception isn't catching runtime exception.

Answer (score 37):

```
catch (Exception ex) { ... }
```

**WILL** catch RuntimeException.

Whatever you put in catch block will be caught as well as the subclasses of it.

Answer (score 14):

Catching `Exception` will catch a `RuntimeException`

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar scenario. It was happening because classA's initilization was dependent on classB's initialization. When classB's static block faced runtime exception, classB was not initialized. Because of this, classB did not throw any exception and classA's initialization failed too.

```
class A{//this class will never be initialized because class B won't intialize
  static{
    try{
      classB.someStaticMethod();
    }catch(Exception e){
      sysout("This comment will never be printed");
    }
 }
}

class B{//this class will never be initialized
 static{
    int i = 1/0;//throw run time exception 
 }

 public static void someStaticMethod(){}
}
```

And yes...catching `Exception` will catch run time exceptions as well.

Answer (score -2):

```
class Test extends Thread
{
    public void run(){  
        try{  
            Thread.sleep(10000);  
        }catch(InterruptedException e){  
            System.out.println("test1");
            throw new RuntimeException("Thread interrupted..."+e);  
        }  

    }  

    public static void main(String args[]){  
        Test t1=new Test1();  
        t1.start();  
        try{  
            t1.interrupt();  
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("test2");
            System.out.println("Exception handled "+e);
        }  

    }  
}
```

Its output doesn't contain test2 , so its not handling runtime exception. 
@jon skeet, @Jan Zyka

Comment: The thread which is throwing the RuntimeException isn't the thread that is trying to catch the exception. That has nothing to do with whether it's RuntimeException or not. Your `main` method has successfully managed to interrupt the thread, so *that* `try` block has nothing to catch. There's then separately a `RuntimeException` which is thrown up the stack and not caught by anything (in user code) because there's nothing *in* the stack to catch it.

Comment: Tho answer is flaw but still enlightening