# which of these two block would catch more exceptions , Exception or RuntimeException

Tags: java

or are they the same ?

```
} catch (RuntimeException re) {
...
}
```

or

```
} catch (Exception e) {
...
}
```

Comment: Either is bad practice.  Catch the specific exceptions you can handle.

Comment: I think this help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164020/why-doesnt-catching-exception-catch-runtimeexception

Comment: RuntimeException and its subclasses are unchecked while Exception and its subclasses, excluding the RuntimeException and its subclasses are checked. unchecked methods have not to be declared in a method or have to been thrown by a class's constructor

Comment: If I may emphasize Dodd10x's point:  Both of those are very bad practice.  Both catch unchecked exceptions, which in almost all cases should never be caught, because they expose programmer errors.  Catching them won't make your code work, it will just make it considerably harder to understand why your code doesn't work.

Comment: @VGR thats not true! Only RunetimeException and its subclasses are unchecked, proven through the documentation. Or is it just a bad choice of words.. well I kinda get what you want to say

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RuntimeException` extends `Exception`, so `Exception` is strictly broader.  (And they're not the same; e.g. `IOException` is an `Exception` but not a `RuntimeException`.)

Comment: Additionally to his answere the Sun' documentation is your friend: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html