# Understanding the Try Catch block behavior

Tags: java, try-catch

I ran into a strange problem with try catch which got me doubting about my own realization of exception handling fundamentals. As per the basic syntax

```
try{
      code to  be checked     
   }
catch(Exception e){}
finally{}
```

However the code below gives me a null pointer exception which I believe should have been caught.

```
class Ideone
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{



    try{

            for(Model m: Null Collection coming from DB)
            System.out.println("Inner Block");

      System.out.println("Outer Block");        

    }catch(Exception e){}

}
}
```

Comment: The collection is `null`. You can't iterate over a null collection

Comment: @Vinod Madyalkar the point is why isn't it being caught by the catch Block

Comment: @amanshivhare - How do you know that it is not getting caught?

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar because I am getting an error at that point ?  Process: com.example.aman.navtest2, PID: 6207
    java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Why don't you have a sysout in your catch block to check if it is getting caught or not?. Or debug through your code?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet prints "An exception!"

```
List<String> strings = null;
try {
    for (String s : strings) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("An exception!");
}
```

And as others have pointed out, and you stated yourself, [Runtime exceptions are caugth by Exception catches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19164070/5524238)

Have you tried recompiling all your code from scratch? In my team (250.000 lines codebase) using eclipse we sometimes have trouble with bad compiles that can give unexplainable problemes like this. We usually solve them by a complete recompile.

Comment: Runnsjo that suprisingly solved the problem. (Rebuilding Project)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about your issue? I believe there's some clean-up code in your catch which hasn't been initialized yet - hence the exception. Would help if you post your actual code.
The following works as expected:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List i=null;
    try{
        for(Object o: i) {
            System.out.println("Inner Block");
        }
        System.out.println("Outer Block");
    }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> Understanding the Try Catch block behavior?

The main reason to use `try-catch` block is to handle something will goes wrong with your code or something you are unexpected for the normal case and something will throw an exception somehow and to handle it in `catch` block, and the `finally` block is used almost to `close` any opened stream and it will run every time in the code even if the `try` or `catch` returned any value (except for system termination).

In your code it seems that there is something you get it from database which is `null` or not initialized yet or it is already returned from database of null value, Now you cannot use `null` object if it's not initialized already! you have to insure if it's `null` or not then use it like this:

```
class Ideone {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        try {
            if(Null Collection coming from DB != null){
                for(Model m: Null Collection coming from DB)
                    System.out.println("Inner Block");
            }
            System.out.println("Outer Block");

        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

The [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) is extends RuntimeException and it's thrown when you try to use a null object.

Answer (score -1):

i has not been initialized,

```
public class Ideone{
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{

    int i = 0;

    try{ 


            if(i<2)
            System.out.println("Inner Block");

      System.out.println("Outer Block");        

    }catch(Exception e){}

}
}
```

Comment: If you changed i = 12, do you know what will happen?

Comment: try changing the     }catch(NullPointerException e){ System.out.println("nulls exist"};

Comment: Irrespective of whether `i` is initialized, this code wouldn't give a NullPointerException, since `i` is primitive.

Answer (score -2):

Cannot reproduce.
I tried this

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Collection c = null ;
        try{ 
            for(Object i:c)
                System.out.println("Inner Block");
            System.out.println("Outer Block");        
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
```

It works well.

Comment: It would print "error" in the console whether or not an exception is thrown.

Comment: It not gives me a null pointer exception, I delete the last line

Comment: Maybe try putting the `System.out.println("error");` in the `catch` block, then you'd see the exception. http://ideone.com/pagkGm

Comment: I know what you mean. But it really can catch the exception instead of throw it out.

Comment: Yes, it catches an exception if one occurs. Your statement that it doesn't give a null pointer exception is simply wrong: a NPE is thrown, however you swallow it without giving any indication that it occurred.

Comment: I'm confused now. You mean this func throws a NPE?

Comment: An NPE is thrown in this code; however, you can't see that because you swallow the exception. There is no way to discern whether it is thrown or not at runtime.