# Catching exception

Tags: java, junit

I am writing a test case using `JUnit` to catch a custom exception `CoreServiceException` that extends `RuntimeException` but some how I am unable to catch it. Please do not mark this duplicate because I am aware of the `@test(expected=Exception.class)`.

Method under test:

```
public AgencyResponse getAgency(@QueryParam(ServiceConstants.AGENCY_CODE) String agencyCode,
        @QueryParam(ServiceConstants.EFFECTIVE_DATE) long effectiveDate) throws WebServiceException {
    ServiceContext ctx = getServiceContext();
    getBaseComponent().logMethodStartDebug(ctx, CLASS_NAME, "getAgency()" ); 

    AgencyResponse response = new AgencyResponse();

    try {
        if( effectiveDate < 1 ) {           
            effectiveDate = new Date().getTime();
        }

        ctx.addParameter( ServiceConstants.AGENCY_CODE, agencyCode );
        ctx.addParameter( ServiceConstants.EFFECTIVE_DATE, DateUtil.convertToDate( effectiveDate, false ) );

        validateRequest( ctx, response );

        IProviderChain providerChain = (IProviderChain)AppContext.getBean( ServiceConstants.AGENCY_PROVIDER_CHAIN );
        response = (AgencyResponse)providerChain.retrieveData( ctx );

        if( response == null ) { //precaution
            response = new AgencyResponse();
        }

        if( response.getAgency() == null ) {
            if(ctx.getMessages()==null || ctx.getMessages().isEmpty()){
                ctx.addMessage( ErrorMessageUtil.generateMessage( getBaseComponent().getMessageFactory(), ErrorCodeConstants.STATUS_2000 ) );
            }
        }

        return (AgencyResponse)finalizeResponse( response, ctx );
    } catch( CoreServiceException ce ) {
        getBaseComponent().logException(ctx, CLASS_NAME, ce);

        response.addMessage( ErrorMessageUtil.generateMessage( getBaseComponent().getMessageFactory(), ErrorCodeConstants.STATUS_5000 ) );
        throw new WebServiceException( Response.status( Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR ).entity( finalizeResponse(response, ctx) ).build() );
    } catch( WebServiceException e ) {
        throw e;
    } catch( Throwable t ) {
        getBaseComponent().logException(ctx, CLASS_NAME, t);

        response.addMessage( ErrorMessageUtil.generateMessage( getBaseComponent().getMessageFactory(), ErrorCodeConstants.STATUS_5000 ) );
        throw new WebServiceException( Response.status( Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR ).entity( finalizeResponse(response, ctx) ).build() );
    } finally {     
        getBaseComponent().logMethodEndDebug(ctx, CLASS_NAME, "getAgency()" ); 
    }
}
```

JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void testgetAgency() {
    setUp( "Producer/Retrieve");
    AppContext.setApplicationContext( applicationContext );
    setSecurityUser();
    AgencyResponse resp = null;

    try {
        resp = getAgency( null, 0 );
        fail();
    } catch( WebServiceException e ) {
        assertNotNull( e.getResponse() );
        AgencyResponse ar = (AgencyResponse)e.getResponse().getEntity();
        assertTrue( ar.getMessages().size() == 1 );
        assertEquals( "message:agencyCode", ar.getMessages().get( 0 ).getMessageText() );
    }

    resp = getAgency( "123456", 0 );
    assertNotNull( resp );
    assertNotNull( resp.getAgency() );
    assertEquals( "123456", resp.getAgency().getAgencyCode() );

    //Test Provider Exception
    resp = getAgency( "000000", 0 );
    assertTrue( resp.getMessages().size() == 2 );
    assertEquals( "message:TestProducerProvider", resp.getMessages().get( 0 ).getMessageText() );
    assertEquals( "message:0", resp.getMessages().get( 1 ).getMessageText() );  

    //Test Provider Exception
    try {
        resp = getAgency( "999999", 0 );
        fail();
    } catch( WebServiceException e ) {
        assertNotNull( e.getResponse() );
        AgencyResponse ar = (AgencyResponse)e.getResponse().getEntity();
        assertTrue( ar.getMessages().size() == 2 );
        assertEquals( "message:5000", ar.getMessages().get( 0 ).getMessageText() );
        assertEquals( "message:0", ar.getMessages().get( 1 ).getMessageText() );
    }}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: So it crashes the program instead of caching it? If so please post the stacktrace

Comment: It throws AssertionFailedError where I am invoking JUnit's fail().

Comment: If it's not being caught are you certain it's actually being thrown when you think it is?

Comment: From the code that you've posted there's no way for us to know if that exception actually gets thrown at all, and if it's not being caught then it's likely that it isn't.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164020/why-doesnt-catching-exception-catch-runtimeexception

Comment: As an aside I prefer to have less "assertions" in one test. Maybe you could split the exceptional tests into a separate unit test?

Comment: I just got it resolved. I am able to catch the exception now. Thank you all.